# Get second row from a SQLAlchemy query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I can get the first value using `myQuery.first()`, but I want to get the second row/value. How can I do that?

```py
myQuery = db.session.query(Inquiry).order_by(func.count(Ruling.id).desc()).limit(2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use myQuery[1] to get the second row. After you used your query.

Answer (score 3):

after limit function, use index to find it

```
myQuery = db.session.query(Inquiry).order_by(func.count(Ruling.id).desc()).limit(2)[1]
```

Comment: What does it do? Provide an explanation of what it does.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished by applying [offset](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.offset) to the returned query, and then getting the [first()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.first) result:

```
db.session.query(Inquiry).order_by(func.count(Ruling.id).desc()).offset(1).first()
```

This has the advantage that it doesn't raise an exception if there are no results - though, you could use [one()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.one) if you did want an exception in this case.

Edit: I also found that if you need to handle the case where there may not be a previous row, and you want to fallback to the first row, you can do:

```
db.session.query(Inquiry).order_by(func.count(Ruling.id).desc()).limit(2)[-1]
```

The `[-1]` in this case gets you the last element in the list - so if the query returns 2 elements, you get the second element. But if it only returns 1 element, you get that one. Though this would raise an index out of range exception if no elements are returned.